# How to use try-with-resources with if statement?

Tags: java, resources, java-7, try-with-resources

I have the simple code:

```
try (FileReader file = new FileReader(messageFilePath);
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file)) {

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        ////
    }
}
```

I want to write something like this:

```
FileReader file = null;
///.....

try (file = (file == null ? new FileReader(messageFilePath) : file);
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file)) {

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        ////
    }
}
```

It would allow me to reuse `FileReader`. Is it possible? If not, how to correctly reuse `FileReader`?

**P.S.**
I use Java 8, if it is important.

Comment: Why do you need to reuse the `FileReader`? All of its lines are consumed.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I consume all line of this file many times.

Comment: You'll need a new file reader for that.

Comment: If the FileReader is used in the try with resources, it will be auto-closed after you leave the try block. Are you sure you want to be reusing it?

Comment: @Dogs, SotiriosDelimanolis, it seems, that I was wrong. I thought, that I have optimized code, if I will reuse this object.

Comment: I don't think you can reset a FileReader like that, you'll need a new one anyway - or to store the lines of the file in memory.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, what I can do, if size of all lines more, than there is available RAM?

Comment: Create a new FileReader or the equivalent, without trying to reuse the first one.

Comment: Thanks guys. I realized my mistake, I'm going to reconsider my task.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You always have to define a new variable part of try-with-resources block. **It is the current limitation of the implementation in Java 7/8**. In Java 9 they consider supporting what you asked for natively.

You can however use the following small trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileReader file = null;
    String messageFilePath = "";

    try (FileReader reader = file = (file == null ? new FileReader(messageFilePath) : file);
            BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(file)) {

        String line;

        while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
            ////
        }
    }
}
```